# How can I prevent my footer from getting overflowed in xsl-fo?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm generating a pdf from my xsl and xml files wherein I need to display a table at the end of the first page. But since there are some tables above this table also, displaying it as static text pushes it down to the 2nd page (or 3rd and so on). So i thought to make this table as a footer (just on the first page).

So I have this table defined as a footer in my xsl file. My table is under the following code
`<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" font-size="10pt">`

When I try to generate the pdf, some of my rows from the footer table are getting overflowed and are not visible on the pdf. (I think this has to do with the fixed size of region-after section)

How can I fix it so that I can get all of my text in the footer?

Comment: I have solved this problem, but a new problem came because of that. I increased the extent value in <fo:region-after extent="4cm"/> so as to see my complete footer. But now my region-body is overlapping with my footer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it. For all those who are having the same problems - increase the value of the "extent" attribute in `<fo:region-after extent="4cm"/>`.

Then add the attribute "space-after" - `<fo:region-body space-after="125pt"/>`.

It solves both the problems - footer overflow and region-body and region-after overlap.